# Number of unordered tuples $(p(x),q(x))$ of degree $4$ polynomials such that $p(1)+q(1)=26$ and $(p(x)q(x))^7$ has exactly one odd coefficent

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Recently, I hav ìe found this problem:

> Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ two polynomials, with positive integers coefficents, of degree $4$ such that $p(1)+q(1)=26$. How many unordered tuples $(p(x),q(x))$ are there such that:
> $$W(x)=(p(x)q(x))^7$$
> has exactly one odd coefficent?

The only way I have found to solve this problem is bruteforcing. In fact, I defined:
$$p(x)=a_px^4+b_px^3+c_px^2+d_px+e_p$$
and:
$$q(x)=a_qx^4+b_qx^3+c_qx^2+d_qx+e_q$$
with all coefficents positive integers, greater or equal to $1$.

Then, I started working out the first condition:
$$p(1)+q(1)=26$$
Substituing $x=1$, I have:
$$a_p+a_q+b_p+b_q+c_p+c_q+d_p+d_q+e_p+e_q=26$$

I think this is a very complicated approach, because then I have to workout the coefficents of $W(x)$ that is a polynomial of seven degree. So, there are any other idea? Or, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By looking at polynomials over the integers mod $2$, the condition that $W$ has exactly one odd coefficient is equivalent to $p$ and $q$ each having exactly one odd coefficient.  Subtract $1$ from the odd coefficients, $2$ from the even, and you have two $5$-tuples of nonnegative even numbers that add to $8$. Divide by $2$ and they are $5$-tuples of nonnegative integers that add to $4$.

Comment: So, in order o satisfy the condition there are $10$ tuples of polynomials?